# Single Header and Footer File

Tags: php, menu, seo

I am wanting to create a single file for my header (including menu) and footer so I don't have to edit every single file. Eventually set up a mobile version of our site (including this info in case it is relevant to method).

From what I have read, the easiest way to have single header/menu/footer files is to use PHP and implement a 301 redirect in order to maintain SEO rankings.

Is this correct?

Our web hosting service has Apache handling (.cgi .pl .plx .ppl .perl .shtml).

Comment: How you create your html will not affect SEO rankings (except when it would take too long maybe). As such, your question is unclear. Why ask about php when your server does not support it? And why would there be redirects?

Comment: Why would you assume that my server doesn't support it? It does.

Comment: From what I was reading, if I was to change a page to a .php (or rename it in any way), Google recommends using a 301 redirect.

Answer (score 0):

You can look into a templating engine like Twig.
you can create a base template that includes the header and footer, and extend that in all your other templates to override the body

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm oversimplifying the problem, but can you not just write header.php and footer.php and just:

```
<?php include 'header.php'; ?>

[content here]

<?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
```

Comment: I have tried this and it isn't working. My test page file is downloads.html. In that page I have:

[html code]

<?php include 'php/header.php'; ?/

[more html code]

I have a separate folder for my php files. I have tried various changes such as using " instead of ' and inserting brackets as I have seen in some other examples.

Comment: Can you edit your origins question to include proper formatted code so I can read it?

Answer (score 0):

in header part you can write the navigation code and and save as header.php and same thing as footer.php what do you want to write in footer section and save and where do you want to include you can include as

content